# Reading Multiple SequnceFiles in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Is there a way to read Multiple Sequence Files in a single go?

```
sc.SequnceFile(['filepath_1.seq','filepath_2.seq','filepath_3.seq'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use glob pattern

```
sc.SequnceFile('filepath_*.seq')
```

or comma-separated strings:

```
sc.SequnceFile(",".join(['filepath_1.seq', 'filepath_2.seq', 'filepath_3.seq']))
```